# Run bash script on `cd` command

Tags: python, ruby, linux

I'm python developer and most frequently I use [buildout](http://www.buildout.org/en/latest/) for managing my projects. In this case I dont ever need to run any command to activate my dependencies environment.

However, sometime I use virtualenv when buildout is to complicated for this particular case.

Recently I started playing with ruby. And noticed very useful feature. Enviourement is changing automatically when I `cd` in to the project folder. It is somehow related to `rvm` nad `.rvmrc` file.

I'm just wondering if there are ways to hook some script on different bash commands. So than I can `workon environment_name` automatically when `cd` into to project folder.

**So the logic as simple as:**

When you `cd` in the project with `folder_name`, than script should run `workon folder_name`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash: custom PS1 with nice working directory path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687446/bash-custom-ps1-with-nice-working-directory-path)

Comment: @tripleee Sorry, but this is very different question.

Comment: @Pol: Well, if your shell supports evaluating arbitrary expressions in PS1, you _could_ write a function that detects whether you've changed directories since last prompt, and whether the new directory is a venv directory, and if so activates it. But this would be very, very silly. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One feature of Unix shells is that they let you create *shell functions*, which are much like functions in other languages; they are essentially named groups of commands. For example, you can write a function named `mycd` that first runs `cd`, and then runs other commands:

```
function mycd () {
    cd "$@"
    if ... ; then
        workon environment
    fi
}
```

(The `"$@"` expands to the arguments that you passed to `mycd`; so `mycd /path/to/dir` will call `cd /path/to/dir`.)

As a special case, a shell function actually supersedes a like-named builtin command; so if you name your function `cd`, it will be run instead of the `cd` builtin whenever you run `cd`. In that case, in order for the function to call the builtin `cd` to perform the actual directory-change (instead of calling itself, causing infinite recursion), it can use Bash's `builtin` builtin to call a specified builtin command. So:

```
function cd () {
    builtin cd "$@"    # perform the actual cd
    if ... ; then
        workon environment
    fi
}
```

(Note: I don't know what your logic is for recognizing a project directory, so I left that as `...` for you to fill in. If you describe your logic in a comment, I'll edit accordingly.)

Comment: Thank you. This is pretty obvious solution, though. I dont think that this is the ruby guys way.

Comment: @Pol: I don't know about the Ruby feature that you mention, but I don't see what's wrong with an "obvious solution"!

Comment: dont get me wrong. I did not say that it is not appropriate. I would say it advanced way. I just feel it a bit to much to recompile cd command for this kind of stuff. I believe that there suppose to be easier ways.

Comment: By the way I added the logic.

Comment: @Pol: Sorry, I think you've *completely* misunderstood this answer. This is actually a very easy way, and does not require any sort of "compiling". I guess you're not familiar with shell functions? I'll edit my answer to add more information . . .

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for one of two things.

[`autoenv`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv) is a relatively simple tool that creates the relevant bash functions for you. It's essentially doing what ruakh suggested, but you can use it without having to know how the shell works.

[`virtualenvwrapper`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper) is full of tools that make it easier to build smarter versions of the bash functions—e.g., switch to the venv even if you `cd` into one of its subdirectories instead of the base, or track venvs stored in `git` or `hg`, or … See the [Tips and Tricks](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tips.html) page.

The [Cookbook for `autoenv`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv/wiki/Cookbook), shows some nifty ways ways to use the two together.

Answer (score 0):

Just found in the description of virtualenvwraper [this topic](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tips.html#changing-the-default-behavior-of-cd)

It describes exactly what I need.