# Not getting proper prompt when using SHH

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, prompt

I logged into my account on Bluehost using SSH and I got an unusual prompt.

I expected it to show the directory and a typical prompt but instead got some `bash`. 
[image: bash]

Comment: The /etc/passwd file normally tells which shell the users will have and use. And if this is "unusual" to you, maybe your shell provider changed the default behavior to use some other shell/some other version of bash. Easiest would probably be to contact Bluehost and ask them.
Or you can just try to execute /bin/bash and see if that reflects what you usually see at login.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687446/bash-custom-ps1-with-nice-working-directory-path take a look here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is the default bash prompt. This is what you get when the distro doesn't provide a better one in `/etc/profile` or similar. You can get it on any platform by ignoring the environment and config files:

```
env -i bash --norc
```

To get the `user@host:dir$` prompt that Debian and derived distros use, you can add

```
export PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

to your `.bash_profile`