# Bash rename screen tab on ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, gnu-screen, screenrc

I am using multiple tabs with "screen" in bash and I have setup the following to rename the tab to the target hostname if I ssh in that tab:

$HOME/.ssh_hostname

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -ne "\033k$1\033\\"
```

$HOME/.ssh/config

```
PermitLocalCommand yes
LocalCommand ~/.ssh_hostname %h
```

This works great, but the one thing I'd like to do is rename it back to "default" when I exit the ssh session. Right now it just keeps the tab renamed even if I exit ssh.

Any ideas about how I could re-rename it when I exit ssh?

Comment: Use a function (or alias) for ssh that sets it back when `ssh` finishes? I don't know that `ssh` can do this for you (but I haven't ever really looked for it either).

Comment: Can you put whatever change you want into your `~/.bash_logout` file?

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687642/set-screen-title-from-shellscript ?